# Need a solid way to set relational indices for object polygons drawn in a canvas element

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs, gsap

Okay this is going to be hard to explain. So bear with me.

Im having less of a problem with the programming, and more a problem with the idea behind what Im trying to do.

I have a grid of triangles. Ref: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxPDD.png [1]

Each triangle is it's own polygon on a canvas element that I have set as an object within the code. The only difference between the objects is the coordinates that I pass through as parameters of a function like so:

```
var triCoordX = [1, 2, 3, ...];
var triCoordY = [1, 2, 3, ...];
var triCoordFlipX = [1, 2, 3, ...];
var triCoordFlipY = [1, 2, 3, ...];


var createTri = function(x, y, z) {
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        sides: 3,
        radius: 15,
        rotation: z,
        fillRed: 17,
        fillGreen: 17,
        fillBlue: 17,
        closed: true,
        shadowColor: '#5febff',
        shadowBlur: 5,
        shadowOpacity: 0.18
    }
};

for (i = 0; i < triCoordX.length; i++){ 
    var tri = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon(createTri(triCoordX[i], triCoordY[i], 0));
}

for (i = 0; i < triCoordFlipX.length; i++){ 
    var triFlip = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon(createTri(triCoordFlipX[i], triCoordFlipY[i], 180));
}
```

Now what Im trying to do exactly is have each object polygon be able to 'recognise' its neighbors for various graphical effects.

How I propose to do this is pass a 4th parameter into the function that I push from another array using the for loop that sets a kind of "index" for each polygon. Also in the for loop I will define a function that points to the index 'neighbors' of the object polygon.

So for instance, if I want to select a random triangle from the grid and make it glow, and on completion of a tween want to make one of it's neighbors glow I will have the original triangle use it's object function to identify a 'neighbor' index and pick at random one of its 3 'neighbors'.

The problem is with this model, Im not entirely sure how to do it without large amounts of bloat in my programming, or when I set the function for the loop, to set a way for the loop to intuitively pick the correct index numbers for what are actually the triangle's neighbors.

If all of that made sense, Im looking for any and all suggestions.

Comment: JS is 'OO' language. Why don't you define reference in one object to point to neighbors?

Comment: @Danyu Hmmm Im either not sure how to do that, or not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of your triangles as being laid out in a grid with the triangle in the top left corner being col==0, row==0.

Then you can find the row/col coordinates of the 3 neighbors of any triangle with the following function.

Ignore any neighbors with the following coordinates because the neighbors would be off the grid.

- col<0
- row<0
- col>ColumnCount-1
- row>RowCount-1

Example code (warning...untested code--you may have to tweak it):

```
function findNeighbors(t){

    // determine if this triangle's row/col are even or odd
    var evenRow=(t.col%2==0);
    var evenCol=(t.row%2==0;

    // left neighbor is always the same
    n1={ col:t.col-1, row:t.row };

    // right neighbor is always the same
    n2={ col:t.col+1, row:t.row };

    // third neighbor depends on row/col being even or odd
    if(evenRow && evenCol){
        n3={ col:t.col, row:t.row+1 };
    }
    if(evenRow && !evenCol){
        n3={ col:t.col, row:t.row-1 };
    }
    if(!evenRow && evenCol){ 
        n3={ col:t.col, row:t.row-1 };
    }
    if(!evenRow && !evenCol){
        n3={ col:t.col, row:t.row+1 };
    }

    // return an array with the 3 neighbors
    return([n1,n2,n3]);
}
```

Comment: Pretty good approach, I actually was looking at potentially making the entire thing a 2D Array of sorts and using the exact coordinates themselves as the marker and doing (pseudocode warning)  `if ((x > a && x < b)&&(y > c && y < d)){ set neighbors as [x1,y1] [x2, y2] [x3, y3] }` as a sort of coordinate threshold to define the neighbors then I just have to set logic to get the neighbors randomly by their x and y attributes.